# R: Google Analytics MCF - Filtering by products

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to filter Google Analytics MCF report by two basic product categories we sell (let's call them type1 and type2).

My current API call via R package RGA is:

```
get_mcf(profileId = 'xxxxx',
        start.date = '2016-10-01',
        end.date = '2016-12-31',
        metrics = 'mcf:totalConversions, mcf:totalConversionValue',
        dimensions = 'mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath',
        samplingLevel = 'HIGHER_PRECISION',
        max.results = 10000,
        token = 'xxxxx')
```

With this I can get MCF paths for all products. 
What I need to do now is to add filter or segment, which would allow me to add filter for product name, something like

```
ga:productName=@type1
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a limited number of dimensions and metrics that you can use with the MCF api.  As far as I can see there is no mfc:productName dimension

You can find the full list of dimenisons and metrics you can use with this api here [Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/)